# Elastic(search): Combine search templates with scrolling

Tags: templates, scroll, elasticsearch

I want to define a search template and use it together with scrolling to retrieve all results. However I cannot figure out how to use it. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Actually I'm also satisfied with other solutions as long as I get all results with a search template. Currently I'm just setting the size in the template to a large number (e.g. 10'000).

Greetings,
Jan